# uasort is removing keys/arrays

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to sort a multidimensional array (in fact that it is multidimensional doesn't matter since I'm always only sorting one dimension).

```
function orderSort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['order'] == $b['order']) return 0;

    return($a['order'] < $b['order']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$nav = array(
    "section" => array(
        "header" => array(),
        "main" => array()
    ),
    "link" => array(
        "header" => array(),
        "main" => array()
    )
);

$DATA = array(
    array(
        "type" => "section",
        "subtype" => "main",
        "data" => array("name" => "/Basic", "order" => 1, "parent" => "bbb")
    ),
    array(
        "type" => "link",
        "subtype" => "main",
        "data" => array("name" => "Home", "link" => array("/"), "order" => 1, "parent" => "/Basic")
    )
);

foreach($DATA as $ele) {
    if(!array_key_exists($ele['data']['parent'], $nav[$ele['type']][$ele['subtype']]))
        $nav[$ele['type']][$ele['subtype']][$ele['data']['parent']] = array($ele['data']);
    else
        array_push($nav[$ele['type']][$ele['subtype']][$ele['data']['parent']], $ele['data']);
    }

var_dump($nav['section']['main']);
echo '<br><br>';

foreach($nav['section']['main'] as $ele) {
    uasort($ele, 'orderSort');
    $nav['section']['main'] = $ele;
}

var_dump($nav['section']['main']);
```

The first `var_dump` returns:

```
array(1) { 
    ["bbb"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["name"]=> string(6) "/Basic" 
            ["order"]=> int(1) ["parent"]=> string(3) "bbb" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

As you can see there is a key named `bbb` (Sorry for that... highly conceptional). Now the second output:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        ["name"]=> string(6) "/Basic" 
        ["order"]=> int(1) 
        ["parent"]=> string(3) "bbb" 
    } 
}
```

Suddenly `bbb` is gone. In fact the whole array (with only a single element) has disappeared.

My question is, can I somehow prevent this from happening? I never asked for this kind of of optimization. Of course sorting this with only one element doesn't make any sense but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($nav['section']['main'] as $ele) {
    uasort($ele, 'orderSort');
    $nav['section']['main'] = $ele;
}
```

Okay. And which is the key? you just forgot the keys (you are overwriting the parent of the original array with a new array instead of the original array itself):

```
foreach($nav['section']['main'] as $key => $ele) {
    uasort($ele, 'orderSort');
    $nav['section']['main'][$key] = $ele;
}
```

would be correct, but by reference is even better:

```
foreach($nav['section']['main'] as &$ele) {
    uasort($ele, 'orderSort');
}
```

Comment: Accepted for recommending reference. (in 7 min.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach($nav['section']['main'] as $ele) {
    uasort($ele, 'orderSort');
    $nav['section']['main'] = $ele;
}
```

This needs to be

```
foreach($nav['section']['main'] as $index => $ele) {
    uasort($ele, 'orderSort');
    $nav['section']['main'][$index] = $ele;
}
```

You were replacing the whole $nav['section']['main'] with the first element.